# How to remove an element of a list from a set of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of list created from `f[vR_] := Map[FindShortestPath[g, vOrigen, #] &, Rest[vR]]` which it's looking for the shortest path between a random node(vOrigen) and the rest of the nodes of a graph(g), to create the set i'm using `Map[f[#] &, verticesRoom]`, the lists of the sets aren't linear,for example, the output when vOrigen it's 9 is like this:

```
{{{9, 1}, {9, 1, 2}, {9, 10, 6}, {9, 10}, **{9}**}, {{9, 1, 2}, {9, 1, 2, 
   3}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 6}}, {{9, 1, 2, 
   3}, {9, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11, 
   12}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 8}}, {{9, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {9, 
   10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11,
    12, 13}}, {{9, 10, 6}, {9, 10, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11}, {9, 10, 
   14, 15}, {9, 10, 14}, {9, 10}}, {{9, 10, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 
   8}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11, 12}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11}}, {**{9}**, {9, 10}, {9, 
   10, 14}, {9, 19, 20}, {9, 19}}, {{9, 10, 6, 7, 11}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 
   11, 12}, {9, 10, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17}, {9, 
   10, 14, 15, 16}, {9, 10, 14, 15}}, {{9, 10, 14}, {9, 10, 14, 
   15}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 21}, {9, 19, 24, 25, 
   26}, {9, 19, 24, 25}, {9, 19, 20}}, {{9, 10, 14, 15, 16}, {9, 10, 
   14, 15, 16, 17}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 
   17, 18, 23}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 
   21}}, {{9, 19}, {9, 19, 20}, {9, 19, 24, 25}, {9, 19, 24}}, {{9, 
   10, 14, 15, 16, 21}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 
   16, 21, 22, 29}, {9, 19, 24, 27, 28}, {9, 19, 24, 25, 26}}, {{9, 
   10, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 23}, {9, 10, 
   14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 29, 30}, {9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 29}}, {{9,
    19, 24}, {9, 19, 24, 25}, {9, 19, 24, 25, 26}, {9, 19, 24, 27, 
   28}, {9, 19, 24, 27}}}
```

but when this function create the set of lists of shortest path also compare with vOrigen and i want to delete the *element*(marked with ** **) of any list identical to vOrigen, since more nodes will be added to vOrigen lately.

Answer (score 2):

Say your list about is called `list`. You can remove all the terms {9} using

```
list /. {9} -> Nothing
```

As pointed out by b3m2a1 and Kellen Myers, DeleteCases also works:

```
DeleteCases[list, {9}, All]
```

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning `DeleteCases` with `Infinity` (or hopefully a more precise level spec)

Comment: I would use level spec `All`, but I think they have the same effect. Is that what you meant by "more precise"?

Comment: @KellenMyers , No, `All` is `{0,Infinity}`, while `Infinity` is `{1,Infinity}`.  But  @b3m2a1 is probably suggesting using `{2}`, as that is the only level at which you wish to delete `{9}`

Comment: An interesting distinction. Is it possible that one could delete `{9}` at level 0 except if `list` were literally `{9}`?